# How to improve concurrency when using Sinatra Server Sent Events stream

Tags: sinatra, eventmachine, thin, server-sent-events, puma

I'm working on building a Rack middleware that subscribes to a Redis channel and pushes the messages out to clients using Server Sent Events. [Sinatra provides a nice DSL for doing this.](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Streaming%20Responses) I have a working example, however, the problem I'm running into is that performance degrades substantially once I get to 7 or 8 clients. I have also run into issues with "dead-locking" the server when trying to reuse a Redis connection between requests.

I'm using Thin to serve the app (which uses EventMachine under the hood). I thought that the Sinatra DSL already handled the concurrency with EventMachine, but maybe this is something that I need to implement myself? I don't want to restrict myself to only EventMachine based servers (Thin, Rainbows!) in case someone wants to use a multi-threaded server like Puma. What should I do to increase concurrency in my code?

```
require 'redis'
require 'sinatra/base'

class SSE < Sinatra::Base

  def send_message(json)
    "id: #{Time.now}\n" +
    "data: #{json}" +
    "\r\n\n"
  end

  get '/channels/:id/subscribe', provides: 'text/event-stream' do
    channel_id = params['id']
    stream(:keep_open) do |connection|
      Redis.new.subscribe("channels:#{channel_id}") do |on|
        on.message do |channel, json|
          connection << send_message(json)
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things come to mind, so I'll iterate those in no partial order.

> I'm using Thin to serve the app (which uses EventMachine under the
>   hood). I thought that the Sinatra DSL already handled the concurrency
>   with EventMachine, but maybe this is something that I need to
>   implement myself?

You are correct, Thin uses EventMachine. However, the thing with EventMachine (or any other reactor) is that once you perform an synchronous operation you halt the entire reactor. So, to truly get the concurrency you're expecting you'll need to continue the use of EventMachine throughout your application.

Checkout [em-hiredis](https://github.com/mloughran/em-hiredis) for an EventMachine ready Redis client that supports pub/sub.

> I don't want to restrict myself to only EventMachine based servers
>   (Thin, Rainbows!) in case someone wants to use a multi-threaded server
>   like Puma

Never tried what I'm about to say, but I don't think you'll have problems using EventMachine within a server that doesn't. Just remember to start your own EM. Perhaps in config.ru?

> I have also run into issues with "dead-locking" the server when trying
>   to reuse a Redis connection between requests

I believe the reason you're experiencing this is because each call to '/channels/:id/subscribe' is opening a new connection to Redis. You can only have so many of those open. Consider refactoring `Redis.new` into a shared connection for your application. Only open it once. A single Redis connection should be able to handle multiple pub/subs.

Just some thoughts, and I hope they help.

Answer (score 1):

After much research and experimentation, here's the code I'm using with sinatra + sinatra sse gem:

```
class EventServer < Sinatra::Base
 include Sinatra::SSE
 set :connections, []
 .
 .
 .
 get '/channel/:channel' do
 .
 .
 .
  sse_stream do |out|
    settings.connections << out
    out.callback {
      puts 'Client disconnected from sse';
      settings.connections.delete(out);
    }
  redis.subscribe(channel) do |on|
      on.subscribe do |channel, subscriptions|
        puts "Subscribed to redis ##{channel}\n"
      end
      on.message do |channel, message|
        puts "Message from redis ##{channel}: #{message}\n"
        message = JSON.parse(message)
        .
        .
        .
        if settings.connections.include?(out)
          out.push(message)
        else
          puts 'closing orphaned redis connection'
          redis.unsubscribe
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The redis connection blocks on.message and only accepts (p)subscribe/(p)unsubscribe commands. Once you unsubscribe, the redis connection is no longer blocked and can be released by the web server object which was instantiated by the initial sse request.  It automatically clears when you receive a message on redis and sse connection to the browser no longer exists in the collection array.

Comment: Thank you for good example, the only thing I tackled a lot is only first connection did work as expected. After research I found that Redis.new should be called in every request, otherwise only first will be handled.